# Azure DevOps blocks multiple PRs from the same branch (to different branches)

Tags: azure-devops

Let's say I want to merge branch "A" onto branch "main", so I create a PR on Azure DevOps. Of course, if I try to create a PR from A to main I get a message that says "An active pull request already exists between the selected branches" and Azure doesn't let me do that, which is totally fine.

However, if I change the target branch to something else (say branch "prerelease"), the same message is still there, even though there is no PR from A to prerelease.

I think this is either a change by Azure or a setting somewhere, because I'm sure that I could do it in the past. Because of our branching strategy, we first merge from a feature branch onto a "UAT" branch, release in UAT, and after we get approval we merge onto main and deploy in production; I used to create both PRs, but I never got that error before. This "new" behavior has been happening in the last couple months.

To sum up, **what must I do to create a second PR from A to C when there is already an active PR from A to B**?

PS: This is annoying also because I use the merge preview that comes with the PR draft a lot, but it won't even let me see what would be merged in the PR. "No preview if you can't do". **What else can I use to see a branch comparison like the one Azure does in a PR?** I think I used something like `git log branchA..branchB` but I can't remember the command any more.

**EDIT** Posting pictures to demonstrate

I have an active PR from branch X to main:

[image: Active PR from branch X to main]

Then I go to "New pull request" and select branch X as the source branch - main is selected by default as target branch. I get the error, which is fine; it even points me to that PR:

[image: New PR is a duplicate: error]

If I switch the target branch to another one (UAT), the error stays (it disappears and reappears, so it's not a matter of stale data). No active PR exists for these two branches; it even points me to that PR, but it doesn't refer to these two branches:

[image: New PR is not a duplicate: error]

Changing the source branch after the target branch has no effect.

Comment: I just tried and I created two PR from master-b to master and from master-b to test-3. Could you share screens?

Comment: I know I used to do that. I've added screens.

Comment: I'm getting this same issue.